# application does not post the user

Tags: facebook, action, publish

we have a faceboook apps  https://apps.facebook.com/starhoroskopy/
It is the application of horoscope, numerology, tarot cards.
User applications can subscribe horoscope, numerology, tarot cards (publish_actions)
Then, every morning the application shares the horoscope (tarot, numerology) to the timeline user. Everything worked several months.  Today it stopped working. Can anyone tell me what happened and how to fix it. We do not know what happened. Tahnk You. 
We use this code:

```
$params = array(
'access_token'  =>  $token,
'message'       =>  "message",
'name'          =>  "name",
'caption'       =>  "caption",
'description'   =>  "description",
'link'          =>  "link"
'picture'       =>  "url picture",
```

);
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/feed';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app was blocked for "negative user feedback"? https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/

Can you also provide curl output?

Comment: Hi Mikolaj, Thank you very much for your answer. I have clicked on the link https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/ Facebook writes: Currently, none of your apps are restricted. I do not know what you mean: Can you also provide curl output? / Please can you explain it to me. Thank you very much for your advice and your time. Have a nice day

Comment: put `$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);var_dump($file_contents);` after your code

Comment: Mikolaj tank you. I send your answer to our developer for testing. It is very nice that you help us and give quick answers. Have a nice day

Comment: Hi Mikolaj,Our developer tried to do according to your instructions.This is the answer: "error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}} Post to users wall still does not work. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Tank you very much. Have a nice day.